# Documentar eventos de node custom

Tags: javascript, nodejs, events, jsdoc

Estoy haciendo un módulo que usa eventos y quiero documentarlos para que cuando estás desarrollando, salga como primer parámetro el nombre del evento y dependiendo del evento tengas un callback diferente.

Mi problema es que no me aparece como segundo argumento el callback que le asigné a cada evento. Mi código se ve así ahora mismo:

```js
const {EventEmitter} = require('node:events');
const gameError = require('../utils/gameError.js')

/**
 * @typedef {Object} testObject
 * @property {number} the number param
 * 
 * @typedef {Object} testObject2
 * @property {number} do number param
 */

/**
 * @callback test
 * @param {testObject} xd the xd param
 * 
 * @callback testear
 * @param {testObject2} yd the yd param
 */

/**
 * Game events names
 * @typedef {["inGame"|"prepare", test|testear, ...any[]]} GameEventsName
 */

/**
 * Listen game events
 */
class GameEvents extends EventEmitter {
    /**
     * @param {GameEventsName} args
     */
    on(...args) {
      super.on(...args)
    }

    /**
     * @param {GameEventsName} args
     */
    once(...args) {
      super.once(...args)
    }

    /**
     * @param {GameEventsName} args
     */
    addListener(...args) {
      super.addListener(...args)
    }

    /**
     * @param {GameEventsName} args
     */
    emit(...args) {
      super.emit(...args)
    }
}

module.exports = GameEvents;
```

[image: Selección de eventos]

[image: No aparece el callback :(]

Cuando selecciono como evento a escuchar `inGame`, debería de mostrarme entre los parámetros del callback uno de tipo `Object` con la propiedad `xd` mientras que si uso `prepare` debería de salir un callback con un parámetro igual de tipo `Object` con una propiedad llamada `do`.

Estoy usando `jsdocs` en `node@18.7.0`

Comment: hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No me ha quedado claro cuál es el problema que estás teniendo. `El problema es que he estado leyendo por aquí y la información que había no me ha servido de nada.` Por lo que leo, tu problema es que la "información que había no me ha servido de nada" pero no entiendo que problema tienes con la documentación de funciones. Te recomiendo que agregues un [example]. Puedes editar tu pregunta haciendo click en [edit]. Saludos!

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta, @AndresGardiol! Ya he editado la pregunta con imágenes, si tienes más dudas házmelo saber, un saludo!